# Update Class variable outside PHP Class

Tags: php, oop, class, variables

I'm gonna make this too complicated, just going to break it down to the main parts.

I have a form that changes the boolean of a variable when the form gets submitted, however it gets called by a function, the function has to change the variable.

```
class updates
{
    var $yesno = false;

    function updateBool()
    {
        $this->yesno = true;
    }
}
```

So when the form gets submitted, it will call `$up->updateBool()` to change the boolean to true. When I do `var_dump($up->yesno)`, it says `false` when it should be `true`. If I do this:

```
class updates
{
    var $yesno = false;

    function updateBool()
    {
        $this->yesno = true;
        var_dump($this->yesno); // <-- outputs true
    }
}
```

So how come I cannot get the variable to print out `true` in a seperate script?

**EDIT:**

```
$sql = "SELECT boolean
        FROM config
        WHERE boolean = 'true'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $up->updateBool();
}
else
{
    header("Location: index.php?d=none");
}
```

This is part of the code where it gets called. I can confirm there are more than 1 record in the SQL statement.

Comment: Please show the exact code you are using when it returns `false`

Comment: And when exactly are you doing the var dump?`

Comment: And where in that new code do you do the `var_dump`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So when the form gets submitted, it will call $up->updateBool() to change the boolean to true

You seem to be switching to a new page, where `$up` will be a new object. Objects do not persist across requests. PHP "loses its memory" when you call a new page, and all variables are started from scratch.

To persist values across page requests, you would need to use something like [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Comment: Hmmm. Your answer seems reasonable, I always thought objects can be passed around in PHP after moving from one page to another. I shall accept your answer due to a logical answer.

Comment: @lolwut sessions are usually the way, although you shouldn't put too much data into a session. For a fancy advanced fast way to persist objects, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940610/how-to-persist-objects-between-requests-in-php

Comment: In order to pass objects around you need to start a session and then assign the object to a session variable.  Otherwise, all objects only exist for the lifetime of the page and recreated each time the page is requested.

Comment: What if the variable/object was meant to be private so it wouldn't be logical to set them into a session that can be tampered with.

Comment: @lolwut who could tamper with a session? It's true you shouldn't store credit card data in one because an attacker might get hold of the temporary session files on the server under certain circumstances, but that is a deep system-level security problem. For most intents and purposes, sessions are safe

Comment: Oh, my bad. I was thinking about those yummy cookies that can be tampered easily that is certainly a security problem when storing stuff inside cookies.

Comment: @lolwut *that* is true, yeah. Nothing should be stored in cookies but chocolate cream. Delicious, delicious chocolate cream.... (drool)

Answer (score 0):

```
class updates
{
    public $yesno;
    function __construct(){
        $this->yesno = false;
    }

    function updateBool()
    {
         $this->yesno = true;
    }
}
```