# PHP APC Seg Fault

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, apc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is APC compatible with PHP 5.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611676/is-apc-compatible-with-php-5-4)

I am trying to get APC to work on (what will be) my production environment stably. I'm getting seg faults when it is enabled and certain libraries are used. It seems to be associated to Doctrine.

Everything is running fine on other machines I use, which are using a newer version of APC that is in beta (3.1.13 and 3.1.11).

Should I be OK to use 3.1.13 beta, or is there a setting I'm missing that will solve the seg faults?

Comment: which version of PHP are you using? PHP 5.4 (usually) won't work with previous versions

Comment: PHP is 5.4.9. APC 3.1.9 is marked as stable, but I do see 3.1.10 denotes PHP 5.4 support. Are any of those betas safe for production?

Comment: well, being marked as "beta" means that you should use them with caution. I've received segfaults with 3.1.10 to 3.1.12, but I haven't tried 3.1.13 yet. I've heard it works better though. Personally, I opted for xcache until a stable APC is released

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611676/is-apc-compatible-with-php-5-4 which is always kept up-to-date

Comment: ok, I'll post that as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP 5.4, apc versions up to 3.1.12 are producing segfaults (personal experience). APC 3.1.13 is said to work better though. Personally, I opted for xcache until a stable APC is released. In any case, using a beta system in production requires some extra caution.

Have a look at [Is APC compatible with PHP 5.4 or PHP 5.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611676/is-apc-compatible-with-php-5-4)  which is always kept up-to-date