# Zend_Form validate crashing PHP

Tags: php, linux, zend-framework, segmentation-fault, apc

Running PHP 5.4.15 / ZF 1.12.3 (upgraded from 5.4.12 or 13 I believe). Running nginx w/ php-fpm, also tested with Apache. *NOTE*: This appears to be related to APC. I would highly prefer APC, and cannot use eAccelerator because of issues w/ Doctrine and DOCTYPE Entity declarations.

When validating the form, it is causing a signal 11 sigsegv across the board (different versions).

Running the form validate inside of the HTML template (shouldn't be a problem)

```
$p = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParams();
if (!$form->isValid($p)) { .. }
```

I dumped out what I could from the backtrace.

```
#0  _zend_mm_free_int (heap=0x22f8800, p=0x28d4130) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend_alloc.c:2100
#1  0x000000000079aefb in zend_hash_destroy (ht=0x28e6cf0) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend_hash.c:560
#2  0x000000000078b657 in _zval_dtor_func (zvalue=0x28e6c30) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend_variables.c:45
#3  0x000000000077dee0 in _zval_dtor (zval_ptr=0x28e83a8) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend_variables.h:35
#4  _zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=0x28e83a8) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend_execute_API.c:438
#5  0x000000000079aefb in zend_hash_destroy (ht=0x28e9180) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend_hash.c:560
#6  0x00000000007b17cc in zend_object_std_dtor (object=0x28e1dc8, tsrm_ls=<value optimized out>) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend_objects.c:44
#7  0x00000000007b1859 in zend_objects_free_object_storage (object=0x28e1dc8, tsrm_ls=<value optimized out>) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend_objects.c:137
#8  0x00000000007b7e87 in zend_objects_store_del_ref_by_handle_ex (handle=128, handlers=<value optimized out>, tsrm_ls=0x22f6090) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend_objects_API.c:221
#9  0x00000000007b7ebe in zend_objects_store_del_ref (zobject=0x28e1ae8, tsrm_ls=0x22f6090) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend_objects_API.c:173
#10 0x000000000077dee0 in _zval_dtor (zval_ptr=0x28e9af0) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend_variables.h:35
#11 _zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=0x28e9af0) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend_execute_API.c:438
#12 0x000000000079aefb in zend_hash_destroy (ht=0x28e99a8) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend_hash.c:560
#13 0x000000000078b657 in _zval_dtor_func (zvalue=0x28e9a00) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend_variables.c:45
#14 0x000000000077dee0 in _zval_dtor (zval_ptr=0x28cb010) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend_variables.h:35
#15 _zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=0x28cb010) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend_execute_API.c:438
#16 0x000000000079aefb in zend_hash_destroy (ht=0x28c8be0) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend_hash.c:560
#17 0x00000000007b17cc in zend_object_std_dtor (object=0x28c4e90, tsrm_ls=<value optimized out>) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend_objects.c:44
#18 0x00000000007b1859 in zend_objects_free_object_storage (object=0x28c4e90, tsrm_ls=<value optimized out>) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend_objects.c:137
#19 0x00000000007b7837 in zend_objects_store_free_object_storage (objects=0x22f9b40, tsrm_ls=0x22f6090) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend_objects_API.c:92
#20 0x0000000000780ec1 in shutdown_executor (tsrm_ls=0x22f6090) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend_execute_API.c:297
#21 0x000000000078cca3 in zend_deactivate (tsrm_ls=0x22f6090) at /root/php-5.4.15/Zend/zend.c:938
#22 0x000000000072390f in php_request_shutdown (dummy=<value optimized out>) at /root/php-5.4.15/main/main.c:1800
#23 0x00000000008523b3 in main (argc=<value optimized out>, argv=<value optimized out>) at /root/php-5.4.15/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_main.c:1952
```

Any experience/insight with this or related issues would be helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: The dump seems to belong to shutdown sequence with several destructors. I am not an expert, but there may be an unhandled fatal error or exception causing this.

Comment: which version of APC are you using? Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611676/is-apc-compatible-with-php-5-4-or-php-5-5 for explanation on what's going on. From personal experience, the latest beta of APC is far more stable than previous versions

Comment: periklis, thanks for linking. I tried multiple versions of APC, to no avail. I've stuck on the 5.4 PHP branch (upgraded a few minor versions) but same result.

When I ran an strace, it did seem to crash right before sending the X-Powered-By header, so I was leaning towards some sort of cleanup/memory issue. I'll wait for a newer APC and give it a go, otherwise maybe throw 5.5 on here as a test. Can't hurt...