# PHP APC extension for Compiler MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)

Tags: php, caching, wamp, apc

Getting error while installing APC extension for PHP.

```
 'D:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_apc.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application. in Unknown on line 0
```

Searched lot and found that need to add proper apc extension as per compiler but mine is **Compiler MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012) and PHP version 5.5.12**.
Tried almost all the extensions , none of them working.
If anyone had this issue please share with me.

Comment: Did you install WampServer 32bit or 64bit. Thats also matters when it comes to finding Extensions for PHP. If you installed the 32 bit WAMPServer you need the 32bit APC extension, if 64bit WAMP then 64bit APC

Comment: This will probably answer yuor questions better than I could. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611676/is-apc-compatible-with-php-5-4-or-php-5-5