# PHP extention APC is not enabled on Windows

Tags: php, symfony, apc, php-extension

I am using WAMPSERVER on my windows.I have downloaded the APC and also APCU PHP extensions and enabled it.Now when I run my Symfony2 project I received error

```
Unable to use ApcUniversalClassLoader as APC is not enabled
```

in phpinfo it is showing like this block [image]

and in my `php.ini` file I have a added following line of code

```
[APC]
;specifies the size for each shared memory segment 8MB to start
apc.shm_size=128M
;max amount of memory a script can occupy
apc.max_file_size=1M
apc.ttl=0
apc.gc_ttl=3600
; means we are always atomically editing the files
apc.file_update_protection=0
apc.enabled=1
apc.enable_cli=1
apc.cache_by_default=1
apc.include_once_override=0
apc.localcache=0
apc.localcache.size=512
apc.num_files_hint=1000
apc.report_autofilter=0
apc.rfc1867=0
apc.slam_defense=0
apc.stat=1
apc.stat_ctime=0
apc.ttl=7200
apc.user_entries_hint=4096
apc.user_ttl=7200
apc.write_lock=1
```

can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: No idea which version of windows or php you are using. However, an internet search: 'WAMP SERVER on windows with apc' resulted in some, possibly useful, results. You can refine the search with windows and php version details. Ensure you download the correct 'apc' version for your particular windows and php build.

Comment: @RyanVincent I am using PHP 5.5 and I have also searched a lot on google but not found any solution.That's why I came here :(

Comment: OK, you have APC configuration, but do you have extension  enabled with 'extension = php_apc.dll'

Comment: which version of windows are you using? win 32, w64, xp, vista, 7 or 8? you need the windows version and the compiler version from phpInfo(). You need the correct apc build for your version of windows and php.  This may be useful: [APC: Download Windows Binaries](http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-accelerators/apc.html)

Comment: A further search leads me to suspect that there is no version of 'apc' on windows for php 5.5. This question may be useful as regards 'accelerators' in 'PHP: [9611676/is-apc-compatible-with-php-5-4-or-php-5-5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611676/is-apc-compatible-with-php-5-4-or-php-5-5)

Comment: it's mean that APC is not longer for latest PHP versions

Comment: I had a brief look at it: This link seems optimistic: [APCu is userland caching: APC stripped of opcode caching in preparation for the deployment of Zend Optimizer+ as the primary solution to opcode caching in future versions of PHP](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu).