# Facing issue with APC installation on wamp server

Tags: php, xampp, wamp

I was trying to install apc on local wamp server, but facing issue. I'm using WAMP 2.5 version on windows 8 system. I installed the apc on `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext` folder. I changed php.ini file also with the below code.

```
[APC] 
apc.enabled = 1 
apc.shm_segments = 1 
apc.shm_size = 64M 
apc.max_file_size = 10M 
apc.stat = 1
```

after that i restarted the apache, But i couldn't identify the apc.dll on PHP extensions.

Can anybody please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the 32bit WAMPServer or the 64bit WAMPServer? As far as I know there is no APC built for the 64bit version of PHP at least prior to PHP7

Comment: Hi Riggs, thanks for your reply, I was using 64 bit WAMP Server.

Comment: This post may be useful information for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611676/is-apc-compatible-with-php-5-4-or-php-5-5